# EJB3 timer not working in Wildfly server

Tags: java, ejb-3.1, wildfly-8

I am trying to create a simple timer in EJB3, example taken from:
http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_ejb_3_16

I created a **dynamic web project in eclipse** and added the following code. I do not see any output

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class ShowCurrentTime {

    @Schedule(second="*/1", minute="*",hour="*")
    public void showTime() {
        System.out.println("Time : " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

}
```

This is also not working in my maven project where the following dependency was added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing?

Edit: 
Updated my code to
    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    import javax.ejb.Schedule;
    import javax.ejb.Singleton;
    import javax.ejb.Startup;

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ShowCurrentTime {

    @Schedule(second="*/1", minute="*", hour="*", persistent = false)
    public void showTime() {
        System.out.println("Time : " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void applicationStartup() {
        showTime();
    }

}
```

All I see in output is the initial print 
    00:48:15,150 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 882) Time : 1414903695150

```
00:48:15,167 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017534:     Registered web context: /Test-DWP
00:48:15,202 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018565: Replaced    deployment "Test-DWP.war" with deployment "Test-DWP.war"
```

Edit:
**Changing to Singleton and Cleaning up deployment directory and redeploying the application worked.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a subtle but important difference between your example and the one presented by Adam.

His example uses a [@Singleton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/Singleton.html) EJB and your's is @Stateless.

The difference means that Adam's example will self start, whereas yours will not start until you create an instance of it.

Answer (score 5):

For people visiting this post in 2017. I just implemented this feature in Wildfly 10 using @Stateless and it does work as it would be expected from EJB behavior.

Example:

```
@Stateless
public class SchedulerInvoice {

@Schedule(dayOfWeek = "*", hour = "*", minute = "*/2", second = "0", persistent = false)
public void invoiceJobHourly() {
    System.out.println("====================== INVOICE JOB START =======================");
    System.out.println("====================== INVOICE JOB END =======================");
  }
}
```